# Which line in the /proc/tty/drivers reflect w command?

Tags: tty

In the web page there is a sentence to describe tty drivers.

[registered tty drivers](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-18-sect-1)

The /proc/tty/drivers file shows all of the currently registered tty drivers.

Here is some info about w and /proc/tty/drivers.

```
debian8@hwy:~$ w
 23:53:38 up 2 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.47, 0.46, 0.20
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
debian8  :0       :0               23:51   ?xdm?   4.62s  0.05s /usr/bin/lxsess
debian8@hwy:~$ cat /proc/tty/drivers
/dev/tty             /dev/tty        5       0 system:/dev/tty
/dev/console         /dev/console    5       1 system:console
/dev/ptmx            /dev/ptmx       5       2 system
/dev/vc/0            /dev/vc/0       4       0 system:vtmaster
serial               /dev/ttyS       4 64-95 serial
pty_slave            /dev/pts      136 0-1048575 pty:slave
pty_master           /dev/ptm      128 0-1048575 pty:master
unknown              /dev/tty        4 1-63 console
```

Which line in the /proc/tty/drivers reflect w command?

Comment: `:0` is Xorg which isn't a tty. That's just the column where a tty would be listed if the user were on one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `w` utility reads the `utmp` database `wtmp` to display its TTY info, as far as I know.  This is written to by `xdm`, apparently by using something called `sessreg` (an X11 utility that "manage utmp/wtmp entries for non-init clients").

The `sessreg` manual says to put a line like

```
sessreg -a -l $DISPLAY -x /etc/X11/xdm/Xservers $USER
```

in the X11 `Xstartup` script.  On my OpenBSD machine, the line actually reads (in `/etc/X11/xdm/Xstartup`)

```
exec /usr/X11R6/bin/sessreg  -a -w /var/log/wtmp -u /var/run/utmp       -x /etc/X11/xdm/Xservers -l $DISPLAY -h "" $USER
```

The `-l` flag has the following description in the `sessreg` manual:

> This describes the "line" name of the entry.  For terminal
>                 sessions, this is the final pathname segment of the terminal
>                 device filename (e.g. `ttyd0`).  For X sessions, it should
>                 probably be the local display name given to the users session
>                 (e.g. `:0`).  If none is specified, the terminal name will be
>                 determined with `ttyname(3)` and stripped of leading components.

As an experiment:

```
$ doas sessreg -a -l hello kk
```

(`kk` is me, and `doas` is the OpenBSD "equivalent" of `sudo`)

```
$ w
 7:31PM  up 10:55, 2 users, load averages: 1.20, 1.16, 1.10
USER    TTY FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
kk       p0 192.168.216.1     8:47AM     0 tmux: client (/tmp/tmux-1000/default)
kk       he -                 7:31PM     0 -

$ doas sessreg -d -l hello kk

$ w
 7:32PM  up 10:56, 1 user, load averages: 1.22, 1.17, 1.11
USER    TTY FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
kk       p0 192.168.216.1     8:47AM     0 tmux: client (/tmp/tmux-1000/default)

$ last | head -n 3
kk        hello                             Wed Jan 11 19:31 - 19:31  (00:00)
kk        ttyC0                             Wed Jan 11 18:54 - 19:21  (00:27)
kk        ttyp0    192.168.216.1            Wed Jan 11 08:47   still logged in
```

In conclusion: `:0` is just a text string put there by the `sessreg` utility. It could be anything, but it's most likely the value of `$DISPLAY`.